# Prevent Postfix from accepting any emails sent by domains in "mydestination" from outside "mynetworks"

Tags: postfix

On our mx's we looked for a way to prevent those servers from receiving certain faked mails. Those faked mails come along using sender addresses my servers are handling and are responsible for, the domains are listed in `mydestinations` and from outside `mynetworks`.

So we created an `smtpd_sender_restrictions` config:

`smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, hash:/etc/postfix/sender_is_bad`

Now `sender_is_bad` looks like:

`domainA REJECT Nice try from outside
domainB REJECT Nice try from outside
...`

in `main.cf` we have

`mydestination: domainA, domainB
mynetworks: 127.0.0.1 192.168.0.0/24`

The idea is to ignore the rules in `sender_is_bad` as long they were sent from within our networks, and to refuse mails coming from outside my networks having our domains in the sender address.

**This works fine, so where is the question?**

I am looking for a way to use something like

`smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_mydestinations`

Any idea? I was walking through the postfix manuals again and again, but was not able to find such a rule. It would eliminate errors when we add new domains to `mydestinations`. On top I think, this should be a standard rule, since usually you do not need to accept such mails as long as you have no external services sending in your name from outside your networks...

Best Regards,
Peter

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you're looking for `reject_unauthenticated_sender_login_mismatch`. This prevents mail being delivered FROM an address, unless the sender authenticated with that address.

Comment: Thanks, Michael. Hm..if I am not wrong it means I would have to configure (again) a lookup table, which is what we have right now as well. My question was more about getting rid of one of the additional tables we have already, called "sender_is_bad". It is just a source for error to maintain 2 tables with domains on machines where we add domains quite some times a year. I am wrong with understanding "reject_unauthenticated_sender_login_mismatch"?

Comment: You already should have a lookup table of authorized users, so they can log in and send (and receive) mail. Postfix will just use that. You don't need another table. The `sender_is_bad` table can go away.

Comment: I do not carry such a table, Michael. We decide based on networks and origins, not based on users or accounts. I guess there is no such thing like an authorized user, we have authorized networks only.

Comment: @PeterStimpel How do you deliver mail to its users, then? Or do you even have users?

Comment: Those machines are "front mx", so they do all the stuff needed to make sure only wanted mails arrive, they handle outgoing transfers, do the DKIM stuff and so on. Incoming okish mails are forwarded to internal groupware servers.